# transform-origin:100% not working for transform rotate

Tags: css, css-transforms

I wanna create brochure which open to the left and the right when someone hover over it. 
I use `transform-origin: 0%` and `transform: rotateY(-180deg)` for the left site of the brochure to open to the left site (Card red and blue). For the right side I use of course `transform-origin: 100%` and `transform: rotateY(180deg)` to open to the right site (Card green).

But the actual behavior of the right side is, that it applies `transform-origin: 0%` and rotates behind the left site of the brochure (Thats why you can't see it, but its there).

I can't understand why `transform-origin: 100%` don't take affect.

here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/eL6q3hp4/2/

```css
.book-container {
  height: 350px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.book-part {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.book-part > .card {
  height: 350px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* RIGHT SITE */
.right-part {
  transform-origin: 0%;
}
.right-card {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.book-container:hover .right-part {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition: 0.7s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

/* LEFT SITE */
.left-part {
  transform-origin: 100%;
}
.left-card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.book-container:hover .left-part {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transition: 0.7s;
}


.middle-card {
  background-color: blue;
}

.right-card {
  background-color: green;
}

.left-card {
  background-color: red;
}

.front-card {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
    <div class="book-container">
        <div class="book-part middle-part">
            <div class="card middle-card"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="book-part right-part">
            <div class="card right-card"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="book-part left-part">
            <div class="card left-card"></div>
            <div class="card front-card"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you mind if I edit your question to put the code directly in the question?

Comment: You can do that, thanks.

Comment: Are the `img` tags without images intentional ?

Comment: My misstake, just think about the img tag as a div.

Comment: your element have 0 width so transform origin will do nothing

Comment: Thank you Temani Afif. This was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove absolute position from `.book-part` and invert the rotation values. You can also add a front card to the right block

I also added transition to the closing effect:

```css
.book-container {
  height: 350px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.book-part {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.book-part>.card {
  height: 350px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/* RIGHT SITE */

.right-part {
  transform-origin: 0%;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.right-card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.book-container:hover .right-part {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}


/* LEFT SITE */

.left-part {
  transform-origin: 100%;
  transition: 0.7s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.left-card {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.book-container:hover .left-part {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="book-container">
  <div class="book-part middle-part">
    <div class="card middle-card" style="background:blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="book-part right-part">
    <img class="card right-card" style="background:green">
    <img class="card front-card" style="background:pink;">
  </div>
  <div class="book-part left-part">
    <img class="card left-card" style="background:red"> 
    <img class="card front-card" style="background:yellow">
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also simplify your code like below:

```css
.book-container {
  height: 350px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  perspective: 1000px;
  background:blue;
}
.book-container > div{
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.book-container > div:before,
.book-container > div:after{
  content:"";
  height: 350px;
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background:yellow;
}


/* RIGHT SITE */
.right-part {
  transform-origin: 0%;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.book-container .right-part:before {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background:green;
}

.book-container:hover .right-part {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}


/* LEFT SITE */
.left-part {
  transform-origin: 100%;
  transition: 0.7s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.book-container .left-part:before {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background:red;
}

.book-container:hover .left-part {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="book-container">
  <div class="right-part">
  </div>
  <div class="left-part">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if in the original situation you work with dynamic sizes (in which case this solution would not apply), but you can use a pixel value for `transform-origin` to make it work:

```css
.book-container {
  height: 350px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.book-part {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.book-part > .card {
  height: 350px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* RIGHT SITE */
.right-part {
  transform-origin: 250px;
}
.right-card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.book-container:hover .right-part {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition: 0.7s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

/* LEFT SITE */
.left-part {
  transform-origin: 0%;
}
.left-card {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.book-container:hover .left-part {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transition: 0.7s;
}


.middle-card {
  background-color: blue;
}

.right-card {
  background-color: green;
}

.left-card {
  background-color: red;
}

.front-card {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="book-container">
        <div class="book-part middle-part">
            <div class="card middle-card"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="book-part right-part">
            <div class="card right-card"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="book-part left-part">
            <div class="card left-card"></div>
            <div class="card front-card"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```